# How to find out API functions of DLL files?

Tags: winapi, api, dll, export

Is there a way to get all the **API (Export)** functions from a **DLL file**?

I know that programs such as **Depend**s and **PE Explorer** can do that but none of them retrieve the argument list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the exported functions are something like a COM DLL or C++ with munging, the information simply isn't there to provide the arguments. It's normally possible to find the total size of the arguments, and there's a pretty decent chance that dividing by 4 will give something close to the right number, but beyond that it's down to manual labor, reading the assembly code to figure out how arguments are used.

If it's a COM DLL, it may include a type library that tells *all* about the contents of the DLL and how to use it. In this case, there will typically be only a *very* few exported functions to look at though -- you'll have to use COM to get at the real functionality.

If they're munged C++ names, then it'll depend on the compiler/toolset used to create the DLL. For example, if it was created with VC++, you can use `UnDecorateSymbolName()` to get the full name and arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I propose this way (with vissual studio 2008 and windows):

1. open a cmd
2. go to

   > c:\..."mvs9.0"\vc\bin
3. exec

   > dumpbin "nameOfDll".dll /exports /out c:\dumpbin.txt
4. open dumpbin.txt

looks like this

```
    ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00001070 ??0CMpeg4Dec@@QAE@XZ
      2    1 000011A0 ??1CMpeg4Dec@@QAE@XZ
      3    2 00001000 ??4CMpeg4Dec@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z
      4    3 00001130 ?CheckFrameType@CMpeg4Dec@@QAEHXZ
      5    4 00001100 ?DecodeFrame@CMpeg4Dec@@QAEHPAE@Z
      6    5 00001150 ?GetHeight@CMpeg4Dec@@QAEHXZ
      7    6 00001160 ?GetPicture@CMpeg4Dec@@QAEPAEXZ
      8    7 00001140 ?GetWidth@CMpeg4Dec@@QAEHXZ
      9    8 000010E0 ?InitDecoder@CMpeg4Dec@@QAEHPAE@Z
     10    9 00001120 ?ReleaseDecoder@CMpeg4Dec@@QAEHXZ
```

1. exec

> undname ??0CMpeg4Dec@@QAE@XZ
>   
>   the output is

```
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "??0CMpeg4Dec@@QAE@XZ" is :- "public: __thiscall CMpeg4Dec::CMpeg4Dec(void)"
```

Comment: Please note there is no space (instead a colon) after /out:"C:\dumpbin.txt"  else it will throw the error LINK: fatal error LNK1146: no argument specified with option '/OUT'

Answer (score 0):

For C++ functions, you can see the arguments (and a few other properties), and **Depends** can de-mangle dem). For C, no luck (C linking is untyped).