# How to find function names from dll using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, dllimport

I am learning how to interact `Python3` with `hardware` using naive windows `dll` files. But using ctypes i'm able to find the `dll` file but, not able to find the exposed functionalities from the `dll`.

I searched in `google`, `stackoverflow`, everywhere and unable to find the solution for my problem.

For Example:

```
import ctypes
data = ctypes.CDLL("WWanAPI.dll")
```

when i tried `dir(data)` functionality i got the following response:
`['_FuncPtr', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_func_flags_', '_func_restype_', '_handle', '_name']`

Any insights will be helpful to find all the functionalities of a `dll`.

Comment: [Starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891493/list-exported-functions-from-dll-with-ctypes)

Comment: This isn't how you do it. You don't get this information from the DLL file. You use the library documentation and header file.

Answer (score 2):

The `ctypes` module provides no such functionality, because there are no functions provided by Windows for iterating the contents of a DLL.

What you want is to inspect the contents of the DLL. It's just a file, and it's in the "portable executable" ([PE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)), therefore you want mechanisms that can read files in that format.

If you just need a command-line tool, look at dumpbin.

A good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24732280/963195
and various good answers here: [Is there a way to find all the functions exposed by a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/437432/963195)

... and here is a module in Python for it:

https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile

Comment: Hi @Andrew E by using https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile can i get description of the functions too.

Comment: Ask yourself this: does the PE format contain descriptions of the functions?